# Is there a way to display <div> firstly by a specified class?

Tags: jquery, html

I'm trying to display a `<div>` firstly by a specified class.

Example :

```
<div><span>1st Pagaraph</span></div>
<div class="showfirst"><span>2nd Pagaraph</span></div>
<div><span>3rd Pagaraph</span></div>
```

Result

```
2nd Pagaraph -> has class="showfirst"
1st Pagaraph
3rd Pagaraph
```

How should I do to find class in `<div>` and show that  firstly ?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please take the [tour] (you get a badge!) and read through the [help], in particular [*How do I ask a good question?*](/help/how-to-ask) Your best bet here is to do your research, [search](/help/searching) for related topics on SO, and give it a go. ***If*** you get stuck and can't get unstuck after doing more research and searching, post a [mcve] of your attempt and say specifically where you're stuck. People will be glad to help.

Comment: Also: Putting completely off-topic advertisements for in your profile is *allowed*, but uncool.

Answer (score -1):

I recommend CSS Grid. You can simply change positions of elements just by using your custom classes, if you want to you can even change their order.
If your `showfirst` class is set to be at the top via CSS Grid, it will appear at the top.
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Grid_Layout

Comment: thanks for sharing css grid but it's not what I looking for. I want to display a <div> firstly by finding a specified class like above example.

Comment: You can create a grid layout with CSS Grid which puts `showfirst` at the top. You can then set the rest to be rendererd after your `showfirst` class. In theory it should work